# Jquery: Stop propagation?

Tags: jquery

I have added stopPropagation, however, I still get two popups in a row. This is better than before, where there were 20 popups for one element that is clicked....is there a better approach or am I missing something ?

```
$(top.document).ready(function () {

    $("*").click(processAction);

});

function processAction(e) {
    var clicked = e.target;
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert(clicked.tagName);
    e.stopPropagation();
    switch (clicked) {
    case "A":
        //execute code block 1
        break;
    case "INPUT":
        //execute code block 2
        break;
    default:
        //code to be executed if n is different from case 1 and 2
    }
};
```

Comment: Do you really intend to stop every default action up the tree for every element? Shouldn't your stopPropagation calls go in the case blocks, and not before them so that only elements you handle explicitly stop propogation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say definitely do not place a click handler on every element. As @Rin stated, you can assign them by tag, or some other selector.

If you *really* want to process all clicks on the page that way, I'd suggest that you place *one* handler on the `document`, and let the click events bubble up to that.

This is much more efficient and there's no need to do `e.stopPropagation()`.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/y6hry/

```
$(top.document).ready(function () {
       // All clicks on the page will bubble up to the document
       //   and fire the handler.
    $(document).click(processAction);
});

function processAction(e) {
    var clicked = e.target;
    alert(clicked.tagName);
    switch (clicked.tagName) {
    case "A":
        //execute code block 1
        break;
    case "INPUT":
        //execute code block 2
        break;
    default:
        //code to be executed if n is different from case 1 and 2
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$('*').each(map, function(key, value) { 
   $(this).click(processAction);

});
```

instead;

Comment: jQuery `.each()` only accepts one argument, so what is the `map` argument? If you use `.each()`, you'll have the same result as the code in the question.

Comment: Sounds like conflating `$.each()` and `$(...).each()` to me.

Answer (score 0):

My little advice: replace `*` with `a` or `input`. Now your code will be more simpler, u could be able remove switch. (I see in switch you inspect what element was clicked).