# How to stop an event propagation in jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$("div#foobar").live('click', function() {  

});

$(window).hashchange(function() {   

});
```

How can I stop firing `hashchange` event when ever `click` event fires.

**Note**
On click event I am firing an ajax and changing the hash ... And on hashchange I am doing something. Since Click event also changes the hash so hashevent fires. So, I want that whenever click event fires hashchange should not be fire ..

Comment: Thanks for the question, I had no idea how awesome the live() method is, I only knew about bind().

Comment: @SidCool: if you think that's awesome, take a look at [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) too. It's more efficient than `live()`.

Comment: What happens when your div is clicked? At what stage is the hash changed? Providing more context would be most helpful.

Comment: Thanks @Town.  I realize now there's a lot in jQuery I am oblivious about.

Comment: I found [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774575/jquery-stop-propagation) useful.

Comment: @karim79; On click event I am firing an ajax and changing the hash ... And on hashchange I am doing something. Since Click event also changes the hash so hashevent fires. So, I want that whenever click event fires hashchange should not be fire ..

Comment: @sillimer - can you post more of your implementation, sounds like there will be a bit of jiggery-pokery involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(function() {

    var fire_hashchange = true;

    $("div#foobar").live('click', function() {  
        fire_hashchange = false;
        // do stuff
    });

    $(window).hashchange(function() {   
        if (!fire_hashchange) {
            fire_hashchange = true;
            return;
        }
        // do stuff
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 10):

stop propagation and prevent default behavior.

```
$("div#foobar").live('click', function(event) {  
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can't do what you want to do.  If you are changing the hash, of course the hashchange event is going to be fired.  That's what it's there for.  Preventing the propagation of the `click` event is not going to prevent the handling of the `hashchange` event.

Design your system so that this isn't a problem.